# Will Azure CDN be helpful on increasing performance of Microsoft bot framework work with Twilio Adapter

Tags: node.js, performance, botframework, twilio-api, azure-cdn

I have a bot developed using Microsoft-bot-framework, And for Whatsapp i am using Twilio-Adapter.
so for performace tuning if i create a CDN for my BotService-WebApp, will that be useful,

CDN works by creating a cache in different POP's and store static & content files there
so when the enduser tries to access website from different location, content will be cached in the nearest region & send response to the end user. But in case of Bot, end user send message in Whatsapp & using twilio webhook botframework will be invoked. so end user is not directly accessing out Bot, its connected through Twilio. Adding CDN to my BotService will work or not?

Comment: Not sure if you are specifically looking to boost up any special performance parameter, but you can refer to these for more details https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/security/benchmark/azure/baselines/bot-service-security-baseline?view=azure-bot-service-4.0#ns-4-protect-applications-and-services-from-external-network-attacks and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-concept-state?view=azure-bot-service-4.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion, CDN will work in your case. Because all the service are from service provider anyway, so create CDN for bot service will be benefit to those contact with service provider. And you need to know that CDN also help user request to choose a better point(not only the nearest, but also a free, well point) to connect to service, e.g one endpoint burst into error or busy. Azure CDN will provide a new url to replace the former one, this is where it will work.

I think any assumption is smaller than the experiment result, you can try to use CDN first to test if it worked. Azure CDN is payed for usage the more you payed indicates the more useful it is.